# CodeIgniter pagination without tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

What i have right now is like 100 divs styled to be 4 in a row, want to add pagination to it, and i succeeded with this code:

```
public function func() {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->database('default');
        $this->load->model('s_model');

        $data['all_rows_s'] = $this->s_model->count_all_s();
        $data['$total_s'] = $config['total_s'] = $this->s_model->count_all_ss();

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/display/s/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $data['all_rows_s'];
        $config['per_page'] = 12;
        $config['num_links'] = 5;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="page_row">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        $data['row'] = $this->db->get('s_data',$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3))->result();

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);


        $this->template->set_theme(Settings_model::$db_config['active_theme']);
        $this->template->set_layout('main');
        $this->template->title($this->lang->line('s'));
        $this->process_partial('header', '/header');
        $this->process_partial('footer', '/footer');
        $this->process_template_build('s_view', $data);

    }
```

But, this is working because WITHOUT table because of this line:
`$data['row'] = $this->db->get('s_data',$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3))->result();`

but i need to make more filters into it, like `order by id` and `where date > NOW()`, how is this possible to do ? what ca i replace this get and the code to still work, and again the view is WITHOUT table, is `divs` within a `foreach`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
**Controller Function**

```
function func() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->database('default');
    $this->load->model('s_model');

    $data['all_rows_s'] = $this->s_model->count_all_s();
    $data['$total_s'] = $config['total_s'] = $this->s_model->count_all_ss();

    /*Pagination*/
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/display/s/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['all_rows_s'];
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="page_row">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    /*Pagination*/

    //$data['row'] = $this->db->get('s_data',$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3))->result();

    $data['row'] = $this->s_model->get_records($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);


    $this->template->set_theme(Settings_model::$db_config['active_theme']);
    $this->template->set_layout('main');
    $this->template->title($this->lang->line('s'));
    $this->process_partial('header', '/header');
    $this->process_partial('footer', '/footer');
    $this->process_template_build('s_view', $data);

}
```

**Model Function**

```
function get_records($limit, $offset = 0){
    return $this->db->where('date > NOW()')->order_by('id', 'asc')->get('s_data', $limit, $offset)->result();
}
```

Comment: The pagination doesnot depends upon the view. It fetches the data from the database as per your queries. It's upto you how you gonna show that info in your site. It can be `table` or it can be `divs`, doesn't matters! :D